# CSS: How can I make 2 HTML input elements to fill 100% of the line, with one growing on account of the other?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scale

I'm trying to place 2 input elements that should, together, fill the width of their container. 
One input elements has type = "text", 
the other input has type = "button".

I want to write CSS such that adding longer text to the "button"'s value will make it grow wider on account of the other element.

I found a [solution for a similar question](http://jsfiddle.net/kxEML/) on SO posted [NSDCars5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1656569/nsdcars5), with an input element and a label element, but I can't seem to adjust it to my needs.

[image: This is what I want]

This is what I have:

```css
#container{
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
}

#a{ 
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#b{ 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="a" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="button" id="b" value="JOIN US! JOIN US!">
</div>
```

And what I want is that the input that says "Name" will grow shorter so that both elements fill 100% of their container's width (and the line wouldn't break like it does now).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox can do that.

Support is IE10 and up.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
}
.wide {
  width: 100%;
}
.a, .b {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="a" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="button" class="b" value="JOIN US! JOIN US!">
</div>

<div class="container wide">
  <input type="text" class="a" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="button" class="b" value="JOIN US!JOIN US! JOIN US! JOIN US! JOIN US! JOIN US! JOIN US! JOIN US! JOIN US! JOIN US!">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overflow: hidden trick (engaging "Block Formatting Context"

```
.container {
    width:400px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid;
}
.left {
    width:auto;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: block;
}
.right {
    height:20px;
    float:right;
}
.field {
     width: 100%;   
}
```

Live example can be found http://jsfiddle.net/7upf46os/
Try to change the button's caption and you'll see it still maintains 400px width.

Comment: In second though: What if I told you that you have to write the class "right" below the class "left" in your HTML ? Is there still a solution?